# For loop in Sprite Kit seems to be emptying an array?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm just starting to wrap my brain around Sprite Kit and I am encountering a very strange error when attempting to change the property of a node in a for loop im using.

I have two SKSpriteNode objects, one is the child of a SKScene (BLATheBugs) and the other is a child of the first (BLAEmptySpaces). I have a grid laid out with BLAEmptySpaces, and BLATheBugs on top of those empty spaces which are supposed to take UITouch, and move to an empty space if its bool isOccpupied property == False. When the scene is set up, the SKScene triggers a method in TheBugs:

```
-(void) spawnEmptySpacesInitialize
{
[self addChild:[self spawnEmptySpaces]];
}
```

which in turn triggers:

```
-(BLAEmptySpaces *) spawnEmptySpaces
{
emptySpace = [[BLAEmptySpaces alloc] init];

emptySpace.numberOfEmptySpacesNeeded = 12;
[emptySpace spawnEmptySpaces];
[emptySpace positionTheEmptySpaces];

return emptySpace;
```

}

which finally triggers a method in the EmptySpaces object:

```
-(BLAEmptySpaces *) spawnEmptySpaces
{
 _emptySpacesArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int x = 0; x < _numberOfEmptySpacesNeeded; x++)
{
    _anEmptySpace = [[BLAEmptySpaces alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"BlueLight.png"];
    _anEmptySpace.zPosition = 50;
    [_emptySpacesArray addObject:_anEmptySpace];
    [self addChild: _anEmptySpace];
}

return self;
```

}

everything seems fine, (except for needing the additional "addChild" in the EmptySpaces object to get them to be drawn on the screen which i have also been trying to fix) but when i call the method to move TheBugs:

```
-(void) moveLeftOneSpace
{
NSLog(@"%d", emptySpace.emptySpacesArray.count);

for (emptySpace in emptySpace.emptySpacesArray)
{
    NSLog(@"cycle");

    if (emptySpace.isOccupied == NO)
    {
        for (_yellowBug in yellowBugArray)
        {
            if (_positionOfFingerTouchX > _yellowBug.position.x - variableOne && _positionOfFingerTouchX < _yellowBug.position.x + variableTwo && _positionOfFingerTouchY > _yellowBug.position.y - variableOne && _positionOfFingerTouchY < _yellowBug.position.y + variableTwo && emptySpace.position.x == _yellowBug.position.x - 80 && emptySpace.position.y == _yellowBug.position.y)
            {
                _yellowBug.position = CGPointMake(_yellowBug.position.x - spaceBetweenBugs, _yellowBug.position.y);

                emptySpace.isOccupied = YES;

                NSLog(@"execute");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It at first tells me there are 12 objects in the array and runs the operation. if I try to move any piece again, it tells me there are now NO objects in the array (yellowBugArray). It is also probably worth noting that it will not let me access emptySpace.anEmptySpace.  Throws me an error.

Sorry for the long post, but hopefully somewhere in here is the cause of my problem.

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: well... that's one way of programming this... haha.

Comment: I'm open to sudjestions

Comment: What I don't understand is your comment about needing to fix addChild. I mean after all without adding a node to the node hierarchy they won't be drawn, this is how Sprite Kit works.

Comment: As far as I understand I addChild twice. I tell the first method to addChild which calls spawnEmptySpaces, which calls the spawnEmptySpace method in the empty spaces object...   I'm working on improving my programming structure and I know I have a long way to go, please bear with me (and thanks for not just insulting me)

Comment: So the addChild method in the emptySpace object's method is the one that adds it to the view, but addChild was the function that initialized this entire process origionally so I dont understand why i need to call it again... does that make sense? :S

Comment: You can't call addChild twice with the same node, that will throw an exception. Same if you feed addChild a nil value. So the problem must be something else, perhaps you're adding some other node?

Comment: i think maybe im mixing up anEmptySpace and emptySpace, which may be the reason i cant access emptySpace.anEmptySpace in my TheBugs object. When i return self in my (second) spawnEmptySpaces method am I returning the array or the object or both?

Comment: At the begining of your function you access 'emptySpace.emptySpacesArray', ok thats fine, but then you turn around in your forloop and say for(emptySpace in emptySpace.emptySpacesArray'), THAT LOOKS SUSPICIOUS. Why are you reassigning the very object that you are searching from? you need to fix thats first, it should be for(id empty_space in emptySpace.emptySpacesArray) or something like that, you shouldnt be using the same name